# How to send Base64 data to server in PHP

Tags: php, base64

**My question is:**
I have an input file with 5-6 fields from which the user would have to select an image and then crop it. So, after cropping, I put these images in an `<img>` tag for preview formatted as *Base64* data.

Now I want to send these images to a server in PHP. I tried to send them as *Base64*, but it shows error of long.

Comment: .can you add your code in question so it will be easy to identify whats going wrong

Comment: sorry but I just only want somehow to send base64 data of 5 or  6 images to php as by post method its say long data cannot send

Comment: I improved some formatting and (tried to) clarify the question. Also did some relevant highlighting.